# How to delete row in Pandas Dataframe using 2 colums as condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Basically, I got a table like the following:

```
Name     Sport   Frequency    
Jonas    Soccer          3    
Jonas    Tennis          5    
Jonas    Boxing          4    
Mathew   Soccer          2    
Mathew   Tennis          1    
John     Boxing          2    
John     Boxing          3    
John     Soccer          1
```

Let's say this is a standard table and I will transform that into a Pandas DF, using the groupby function just like that:

```
table = df.groupby(['Name'])
```

After the dataframe is created I want to delete all the rows where frequencies of all other sports than Soccer are greater than Soccer frequency.

So I need to run following conditions:

1. Identify where Soccer is present; and then
2. If so, identify if there is any other sport present; and finally
3. Delete rows where sport is any other than Soccer and its frequency is greater than the Soccer frequency associated to that name (used in the `groupby` function).

So, the output would be something like:

```
Name     Sport   Frequency    
Jonas    Soccer          3    
Mathew   Soccer          2    
Mathew   Tennis          1    
John     Soccer          1
```

Thank you for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way about it, by iterating through the groups :

```
pd.concat(
    [
        value.assign(temp=lambda x: x.loc[x.Sport == "Soccer", "Frequency"])
        .bfill()
        .ffill()
        .query("Frequency <= temp")
        .drop('temp', axis = 1)
        for key, value in df.groupby("Name").__iter__()
    ]
)


    Name    Sport   Frequency   
7   John    Soccer     1        
0   Jonas   Soccer     3        
3   Mathew  Soccer     2        
4   Mathew  Tennis     1
```

You could also create a categorical type for the Sports column, sort the dataframe, then group :

```
sport_dtype = pd.api.types.CategoricalDtype(categories=df.Sport.unique(), ordered=True)
df = df.astype({"Sport": sport_dtype})

(
    df.sort_values(["Name", "Sport"], ascending=[False, True])
    .assign(temp=lambda x: x.loc[x.Sport == "Soccer", "Frequency"])
    .ffill()
    .query("Frequency <= temp")
    .drop('temp', axis = 1)
)

    Name    Sport   Frequency   
3   Mathew  Soccer      2       
4   Mathew  Tennis      1       
0   Jonas   Soccer     3        
7   John    Soccer     1
```

Note that this works because Soccer is the first entry in the Sports column; if it is not, you have to reorder it to ensure Soccer is the first in the categories

Another option is to get the index of rows that meet our criteria and filter the dataframe :

```
index = (
    df.assign(temp=lambda x: x.loc[x.Sport == "Soccer", "Frequency"])
    .groupby("Name")
    .pipe(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
    .query("Frequency <= temp")
    .index
)

df.loc[index]

    Name    Sport   Frequency
0   Jonas   Soccer  3
3   Mathew  Soccer  2
4   Mathew  Tennis  1
7   John    Soccer  1
```

A bit surprised that I lost the grouping index though.

**UPDATE** : Gave this some thought; this may be a simpler solution, find the rows where sport is `soccer` or the average is greater than or equal to 0.5. the average ensures that soccer is not less than the others.

```
(df.assign(temp=df.Sport == "Soccer",
           temp2=lambda x: x.groupby("Name").temp.transform("mean"),
           )
   .query('Sport=="Soccer" or temp2>=0.5')
   .iloc[:, :3]
)
```

Comment: Ty very much sammywemmy!